# Can't change the height of a div to 100% (but can change the width)

Tags: html, css, height

I'm currently working on a website. I've looked through similar questions but haven't found a solution for my predicament. The changes I'm applying to external and even inline CSS are always being ignored when it comes to height. I can change the width of the div freely, however.

What's going on? What am I missing?

```
<div id="mainsection" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; border: 5px solid red; display: block;">

            <!-- Header
============================================= -->
<header id="header" class="transparent-header style-1 dark no-sticky">

        <div id="header-wrap">

            <div class="container clearfix">

                <div id="primary-menu-trigger"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>

                <!-- Logo
                ============================================= -->
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="index.php" class="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo.png"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Brasillis Idiomas Logo"></a>
                    <a href="index.php" class="retina-logo" data-dark-logo="images/logo.png"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Brasillis Idiomas Logo"></a>
                </div><!-- #logo end -->

                <!-- Primary Navigation
                ============================================= -->
                <nav id="primary-menu" class="sub-title">

                    <ul >
                        <li><a href="index.php"><div>Home</div><span >Brasillis e você</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="quemsomos.php"><div>Quem Somos</div><span >Desde 1992</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="cursos.php"><div>Cursos</div><span >Idiomas e intérpretes</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="servicos.php"><div>Serviços</div><span >Tradução e Transcrição</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="contato.php"><div>Contato</div><span >E informações</span></a></li>
                    </ul>

                </nav><!-- #primary-menu end -->

            </div>

        </div>
</header><!-- #header end -->
        <section id="page-title" class="page-title-parallax page-title-dark page-title-center" style="background-image: url('images/fotos/BrasillisOficialEscuro.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: top center;" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.8">
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <h1 style="font-size: 3em;">Seja bem vindo ao Brasillis</h1>
                <span>Milhares de alunos formados e eventos bem-sucedidos desde 1992</span>
            </div>
        </section>

        <div class="clearfix col_full">
                <div class="col_full common-height">

                    <div class="col-md-4 dark col-padding ohidden" style="background-color: #32587E; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #ccc;">
                        <div>
                            <h3 class="uppercase" style="font-weight: 600;">NOSSOS CURSOS</h3>
                            <p style="line-height: 1.8;">Frontline respond, visionary collaborative cities advancement overcome injustice, UNHCR public-private partnerships cause. Giving, country educate rights-based approach; leverage disrupt solution.</p>
                            <a href="cursos.php" class="button button-border button-light button-rounded uppercase nomargin">Saiba mais</a>
                        </div>
                        <i class="icon-comments bgicon"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-padding ohidden" style="background-color: #F1F1F1; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #ccc;">
                        <div>
                            <h3 class="uppercase" style="font-weight: 600;">NOSSOS SERVIÇOS</h3>
                            <p style="line-height: 1.8;">Frontline respond, visionary collaborative cities advancement overcome injustice, UNHCR public-private partnerships cause. Giving, country educate rights-based approach; leverage disrupt solution.</p>
                            <a href="servicos.php" class="button button-border button button-rounded uppercase nomargin">Saiba mais</a>
                        </div>
                        <i class="icon-briefcase bgicon"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4 dark col-padding ohidden" style="background-color: #339933; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #ccc;">
                        <div>
                            <h3 class="uppercase" style="font-weight: 600;">PORTAL DO ALUNO</h3>
                            <p style="line-height: 1.8;">Frontline respond, visionary collaborative cities advancement overcome injustice, UNHCR public-private partnerships cause. Giving, country educate rights-based approach; leverage disrupt solution.</p>
                            <a href="cursos.php" class="button button-border button-light button-rounded uppercase nomargin">Em breve</a>
                        </div>
                        <i class="icon-user bgicon"></i>
                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: you should post the code in the question before it is answered, so that we don't need to go to an external page :)

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, CSS, HTML, Jsfiddle and etc).

Comment: I thought posting it to an external source would make it easier. I have so many CSS files it's hard to keep track of what's going on anymore.

Comment: Try adding `height:100%` to  `body` and `html` also in your css.It will work..

Comment: I have done that, Lal! Nothing :(

Comment: Using VH instead of % worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: If you want no one to get your code, you cannot post your website online. Once you uploaded it, everyone can get your code.

So let me answer your question. Have you thought about what the 100% means?
If you put more input inside the container ,the complete height will change, actually the paramter height can be higher than your viewport height.
You want "100%" of viewport height, so use "100vh" instead of "100%" !

```
height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 1):

So far I can see is that you used height:100%. This doen't work, I'm not sure why not, but I have a solustion for you.

You can use height:100vh;
vh means: view height, so this means it will take the height of the screen that you are watching it on.